# Foreach loop table results from DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Render.php

```
<?php
class render {
    private $pdo;

function makeSelector($database){
    //Get name and id data from the db. In an assoc array
    $results = $database->Selector();
    echo "<form name='form' method='POST' id='selector'>";
    echo "<select name='train_name' id='train_name' multiple='multiple'>";
    // Loop trough the results and make an option of every train_name
    foreach($results as $res){
                echo "<option value=" . $res['train_name'] . ">" . $res['train_name'] . "</option>";
        }  
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br />" . "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='Add' value='Add'/>" . "</td>";
    echo "</form>";
    }


function makeDetailTable($database){
    //Get all data from database, in an assoc array
    $results = $database->getAllAssoc();

    //Make table headers
    ?>
    <div id="train_select_table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Train name</th>
            <th>Tare weight</th>
            <th>Number of bogies</th>
            <th>Number of axles</th>
            <th>min Wheel diameter</th>
            <th>Max wheel diameter</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>XML</th>
            <th>SQL</th>
        </tr>
    <div id="loopRow">
        <?php      
            foreach($results as $res){
            //Loop trough results, generate a tablerow every time
        ?>
        <tr>        
            <?php 
            echo "<td>" . $res['train_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $res['tare_weight'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $res['number_of_bogies'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $res['number_of_axles'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $res['wheel_diameter_min'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $res['wheel_diameter_max'] . "</td>";
            ?>
            <td> <a href='remove_from_table.php?trainID= <?= $res["train_id"] ?>' > Delete </a></td>
            <td> <a href='convert_to_xml.php?trainID= <?= $res["train_id"] ?>' > XML </a></td>
            <td> <a href='convert_to_sql.php?trainID= <?= $res["train_id"] ?>' > SQL </a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    </table>
    </div>
    <?php
}


}
?>
```

Selector.php

```
Center <br /><br /><br />
<!--Selector-->
<?php

    $render->makeSelector($database);
    if(isset($_POST["train_name"])){

    $render->makeDetailTable($database);
}
?>
```

And the function (db_login.php)

```
function getAllAssoc() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM train_information WHERE train_name = :train_name";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":train_name", $_POST["train_name"]);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
     }

function selector() {
        $sql = "SELECT train_id, train_name FROM train_information";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

Now, this all works.

When i'm on my page i see this:

[image: Start of the page]

Then, when i select a train and pressthe "Add" button, it show me this:

[image: After i hit the Add button]

So that is working.
But now, when i want to select a second train, and press Add. it replaces with this one that already is in the table. But i want it to add another row without removing the first one. Like this:

[image: What i want to happend]

Also, when i go back to index.php (Wich this page is on but the selector.php is a require in there) and refresh the page. it removes the whole table again. 
How do i make the table stay until i like close the application (site)

Also, in the selector you see the name: trein met spaties. (Train with spaces). When i select that the table shows me nothing. (Probaly because the name contains spaces..) How do i fix this?

Comment: Make sure $results contains multiple rows.

Comment: How do i do this?? Since it is a loop, it should automatically make this??

Comment: Loop iterates as much as array depth. if your array has only one iteration eg. $results as only $results[0] and that's it then it will loop for one time only and and print one row. Do echo "<pre>"; print_r($results); echo "<pre>"; and check it $results has multiple array blocks. 
eg. $results[0], $results[1], $results[2] etc

Comment: It only show me 0 @AnandGhaywankar , and when i select an other option it just replaces the information. But it stays 0

Comment: Which means you are not getting multiple rows. Check in DB by running same query used in getAllAssoc() function and check if Table has multiple rows. Else check with PDO fetchAll() function and makes sure you are not missing any parameter. Else your code looks fine to me as far as execution is concern, but in term of coding standard it doesn't look good to me.

Comment: In the db i just get every result :$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73579/discussion-between-anand-ghaywankar-and-mitch).